# Feynman diagrams of phi-meson decay

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, mesons

I am learning how to make Feynman diagrams, and I have a couple of questions about two possible decays of the phi-meson.

The first question relates to the reaction $\phi \rightarrow\text{K}^+ + \text{K}^-$ as seen in the picture below. Each gluon decays into an $u\bar{u}$ pair - I think. I don't know how to interpret the central horizontal line of this diagram. Does it symbolize the annihilation of the last $u\bar{u}$ pair, and if so, why isn't the resultant gluons included in the diagram?

[image: Decay of phi-meson into a positive and a negative kaon]

My second question relates to the decay $\phi \rightarrow \rho ^{+} + \pi^- $ (the left reaction below).
According to the author, this decay proceeds through an intermediary state with at least 3 gluons.
Why isn't 2 gluons enough? That is, why can't the $s\bar{s}$ annihilate into 2 gluons that in turn split into a $u\bar{u}$ and a $d\bar{d}$ pair, respectively, which then combine into the two resultant mesons?

[image: Taken from "Particles and Nuclei" by Bogdan Povh, etc., 7th edition]
The picture is taken from "Particles and Nuclei" by Bogdan Povh, etc., 7th edition

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by horizontal linesee  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OZI_rule . I see an up incoming(antiup by the arrow direction) exchanging a gluon with the s incoming ( antis), andan s and up going out. The correct lower diagram is in the wiki link.

Comment: I refer to the only horizontal line in the diagram.

Comment: well, there is no problem with it

Comment: You *do* understand that the symbolic value of the diagram would not be affected if you raised a little the upper right gluon vertex dot, for instance. Then you could poetically visualize (that's all this visualization is: an intuitive metaphor!) the left vertex as creating a u quark pair, and the right vertex as a gluon absorbed by the quark recently created. As long as you appreciate this is all intuition-building "soft" visualization, not math.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I still don't understand, however, why we need two gluons in this interaction. The strange quark could emit one gluon that in turn could split into an up anti-up pair; this would give the same products.

Comment: A longer story, even though books make it look short. A vector meson has trouble decaying to two vectors; they have to be in a color singlet symmetric state, and the only way to combine to a vector is through a cross product which is antisymmetric. Pseudoscalars can easily decay to 2 gluons, by contrast.